# How to prove Raabe's Formula

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

For quite some time, I've been trying to prove Raabe's Formula, or in other words:

> $$\int_a^{a+1} \ln\bigg(\Gamma(t)\bigg)dt=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)+a\ln(a)-a$$

This is how I tried:
$$I(s)=\int_a^{a+1}\ln\bigg(s\Gamma(t)\bigg)dt$$Differentiating with respect to $s,$
$$I'(s)=\int_a^{a+1}\dfrac{\Gamma(t)}{s\Gamma(t)}dt=\int_a^{a+1} \dfrac{dt}{s}$$
However, at this point I stopped thinking I must have made a mistake because I was told that proving Raabe's Formula was really difficult, and this seemed too simple a method to prove Raabe's Formula. $$$$
I would be grateful if somebody would be so kind as to tell me how to prove this result, as well as what went wrong with my method. Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems correct to me at first glance, and appears to lead you to $I^\prime(s)=\frac{1}{s}$; how do you continue from there?

Comment: Sir, integrating $I'(s)=\int_a^{a+1}\dfrac{dt}{s},$ we get $$I(s)=\dfrac{t}{s}\bigg|^{a+1}_{a}+C$$

Comment: You have $I^\prime(s) = \dfrac{1}{s} \int_a^{a+1} dt =  \dfrac{1}{s} \cdot 1 =  \dfrac{1}{s}$. Now, you integrate with regard to $s$ to get $I(s) = I(\alpha) + \ln \dfrac{s}{\alpha}$, with which point $\alpha$?

Comment: Sir, could you please use dfrac?I'm unable toread the fractions:(

Comment: Sure -- I edited my comment to use bigger fractions.

Comment: Sir $\alpha =1,$ right Sir? Sir, could you please tell me what to do next?

Comment: So $I(s) = I(1) + \ln s$. But then, since you want to compute $I(1)$ (i.e., take $s=1$ at the end), this just proves the tautology $I(1)=I(1) + \ln 1$.

Comment: But Sir then we can't use my method to finally evaluate $\int_a^{a+1}\ln(\Gamma(x))dx$, right?

Comment: That's the point, yes -- your method does not give the desired result.

Comment: there are lots of proofs of this identity on mse...

Comment: Proven in addendum to this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260270/evaluating-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n2-ln-left-fracnn/1260315#1260315

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who told you that the proof is difficult lied.

The proof is simple: take the integral as the limit of the Riemann sums

$$\int_{a}^{a+1}\log\Gamma(t)\,dt = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log\Gamma\left(a+\frac{k}{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(a+\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
then apply the [multiplication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function-Legendre_function) for the $\Gamma$ function to the RHS.

---

This is one of the few cases in which it is faster to compute a Riemann integral from its definition, rather than from the fundamental theorem of Calculus or from integration by parts. Not by chance, the same happens for:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin t\,dt = -\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! Sir, could the proof also be done the way I've tried it?

Comment: You may use differentiation under the integral sign if you define $I(s)$ as $\int_{a}^{a+1}\log\Gamma(st)\,dt.$ Then you have $I'(s)=\int_{a}^{a+1} t\cdot\psi(st)\,dt $, but that is the same as integrating by parts. What you did is just to take $I(s)$ as $\log(s)+I(1)$, not really useful.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, please can you explain what do you mean by the paragraph in end? Great answer by the way!

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: just this: we are used to compute integrals through the fundamental theorem of calculus, rather than through the definition of the Riemann integral. However, in some special cases (like the ones depicted above) to go through the definition is a faster way.

Comment: Ohkk, can we use $\Gamma$ function to compute the integral in the end?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: well, sure, since $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$.

Comment: Yea, but aint it only for $0<x<1$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: such functional identity holds for every $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Okay, and how would we integrate $\log\sin t$ as a limit of a sum? Because the first term gives $\log 0$.

Comment: This (well-known) method seems work only if $a=0$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all note that $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\Gamma\left(x\right)\right)dx=\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right).
 $$ In fact by Euler reflection formula we have $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\Gamma\left(x\right)\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log\left(\pi\right)-\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right)dx\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log\left(\pi\right)-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx\right)
 $$ and the last integral can be calculated using the formula $$\int_{a}^{b}\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx=-\left(b-a\right)\log\left(2\right)-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\sin\left(2kb\right)-\sin\left(2ka\right)}{2k^{2}}.
 $$ Now consider $$F\left(a\right)=\int_{a}^{a+1}\log\left(\Gamma\left(x\right)\right)dx
 $$ then by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have $$F'\left(a\right)=\log\left(\Gamma\left(a+1\right)\right)-\log\left(\Gamma\left(a\right)\right)=\log\left(a\right)
 $$ then $$F\left(a\right)=\int F'\left(a\right)da=a\log\left(a\right)-a+c
 $$ and now if we take $a=0
 $ we find (remeber that $\lim_{a\rightarrow0}a\log\left(a\right)=0
 $), using the first part, that $$c=\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)
 $$ and this complete the proof.

Comment: Wouldn't we need Raabe's formula to know the value of $\int_0^1 \log\left(\Gamma(x) \right)dx$? Seems a bit circular

Comment: @SameerAbbas Why? See my anser, you only need the Euler's reflection formula and how to integrate $\log(\sin(x))$, which can be done using its Fourier expansion.

Comment: Oh my bad my eyes just totally missed that line